# Subject verb agreement when "one of" used

Tags: verb-agreement, relative-clauses, subjects, relative-pronouns

Are these two sentences correct?

1. One of the employees who **is worker** at KP is here.
2. One of the employees who **are workers** at KP is here.

What is the context of **who** in both the sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Only the second one is correct! -- "*One of* **the employees who are workers at KP** *is* here."

*One of*, in that sentence is referring to **the employees** and *who are workers at KP* is a clause referring to **the employees**. *One of* is always followed by a plural noun/pronoun which is always followed by a singular verb (referring to "One of")

Note that the sentence without the clause *who are workers at KP* would also be complete and grammatically correct as follows; **One of the employees is here.**

Answer to **Which employees?** would be, "Those who *are workers* at KP."

Comment: In this case, you are right but there are many examples where the relative clause modifies the lower NP, as in "He's one of those **people** who always **want** to have the last word".